# Microsoft Project showing incorrect end date of task

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2013

I've created a project plan and enabled a custom calendar with working hours of 09:00 - 17:00. I've also checked the project schedule and can confirm that it also shows 09:00 - 17:00, and working hours per day are 8 as expected.

The problem I have is that the end date of the task is being incorrectly displayed as the next working day. For example: a 1-day activity starts on 10 May, and I would therefore expect the end date to show 10 May. Instead it shows 11 May. Similarly, a 2-day activity starting on 11 May has an end date of 13 May, instead of 12.

The plan appears to be assuming that the working day is 2 hours. If I reduce the task down to 1hr duration it shows end date on the same day as the start date. The tasks are set to constraint "as soon as possible." Some screen shots attached.

I'm also not convinced the calendar is being applied to the tasks -- if I click on some random line items they have default calendar applied. How can I force a custom calendar on all tasks in the plan?

[Project information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzdQ7.png)
[Custom Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68t59.png)

Comment: I'm not familiar with MS Project, but you did set the custom calendar to all days from Monday up to Friday and not just to Monday, right? Also, it is not clear to me why you ended up assuming that "The plan appears to be assuming that the working day is 2 hours": Does a 2 hour task also end on the next day?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what was happening. Some of my tasks were marked at 100% complete and this prevented the new calendar being applied to all tasks. No warning was presented so i was unaware that this was the issue. After setting the % complete to 0 i was able to apply the new calendar and its working as expected.
Thanks!